# R: remove overlapping text between similar string variables

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I am using R to manipulate a data frame with N character variables with the same variable name prefix. The variables have similar but distinct contents. I would like to keep the "first" variable as-is and remove overlapping text from the subsequent variables. I can't use `dplyr::str_remove(var1,var2)` because the non-overlapping contents of interest often interspersed within the text. Moreover, there is missingness across the variables of interest.

For example, my input looks like

```
library(tidyverse) 

df_in <- tibble(
  original=c('This is my sentence',
         'Americans spell it summarise',
         "This one uses double quote.",
         NA_character_),
  vec2=c('This is my sentence',
         'Americans spell it summarize',
         "A completely new one.",
         NA_character_),
  vec3=c("Now it's a new string",
         'Americans spell it summarise',
         NA_character_,
         'Here is a new one'))
```

And the preferred outcome would be something like the following.

```
df_out <- tibble(
 original= c('This is my sentence',
    'Americans spell it summarise',
    "This one uses double quote.",
    NA_character_),
 vec2= c(NA_character_,
    'summarize',
    "A completely new .",
    NA_character_),
  vec3= c("Now it's a new string",
          NA_character_,
          NA_character_,
    'Here is a new one'))
```

**Question:** Is there a way to remove overlapping text using tidyverse notation?

I suspect this will have to involve "tokenizing" the strings and deferring to some `stringr`-esque operation or regular expression pattern matching process but, if so, I don't know how to *initially* build out all of the word specific indicators. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: it might be good to build out a few more examples of some edge cases you want covered. For example, if original has `'This is my sentence'`, and vec2 has `'Sentence this is, my my'`, replacing words in original with "" would replace all the words but maybe that's not what you would like

Comment: Also, 'Ice-cream is tasty' and `'R is fun'` could theoretically produce either the full line, or just the words which are different `'R fun'`

Comment: Thanks! I can try to think of a more edge cases. In response to your suggestions here, my question (and examples) only regard  content, not order, hence why I've mentioned tokenizing. Your second suggestion of "R is fun" I believe is spoken for by the 3rd line in the data frame transforming from "A completely new one." to "A completely new ." Let me know if I've misunderstood!

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach:

```
df_in %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(c(vec2:vec3), ~ str_trim(str_replace_all(.x, pattern = paste(unlist(str_split(original, ' ')), collapse = "|"), replacement = ""))), # for any word in the current row and the column original, replace it with ""
    across(c(vec2:vec3), ~ ifelse(.x == '', NA_character_, .x))) # replace ''s with NAs

  original                     vec2               vec3                 
  <chr>                        <chr>              <chr>                
1 This is my sentence          NA                 Now it's a new string
2 Americans spell it summarise summarize          NA                   
3 This one uses double quote.  A completely new . NA                   
4 NA                           NA                 Here is a new one
```